# Pandas: Assign value to dataframe of list of elements if it exists

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign value from element in a list, if it `startswith` this substring to pandas data frame column

Code:

```
searchwords = ['harry','harry potter','lotr','secret garden']

l1 = [1, 2, 3,4,5]
l2 = ['Harry Potter is a great book',
      'Harry Potter is very famous',
      'I enjoyed reading Harry Potter series',
      'LOTR is also a great book along',
      'Have you read Secret Garden as well?'
]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':l1,'text':l2})
df['text'] = df['text'].str.lower()
```

Data Preview:

```
   id   text
0   1   harry potter is a great book
1   2   harry potter is very famous
2   3   i enjoyed reading harry potter series
3   4   lotr is also a great book along
4   5   have you read secret garden as well?
```

Tried:

```
df.loc[df['text'].str.startswith(tuple(searchwords)),'tags'] if (df['text'].str.startswith(tuple(searchwords))) == True else np.NaN
```

Error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` What am I doing wrong? I thought you could assign the value `== True` in the if/else logic

Looking for output like this:

```
   id   text                                     tags
0   1   harry potter is a great book             harry;harry potter
1   2   harry potter is very famous              haryy;harry potter
2   3   i enjoyed reading harry potter series    NaN
3   4   lotr is also a great book along          lotr
4   5   have you read secret garden as well?     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `apply`:

```py
df['tags'] = df.text.apply(
    lambda text: [searchword for searchword in searchwords if text.startswith(searchword)]
)
```

This gives you the column `tags` containing a lists of the respective tags, like so:
[image]

If you prefer `nan` over empty lists `[]`, you can do so in a second step.

```
df['tags'] = df.tags.apply(
    lambda current_tag: float('nan') if len(current_tag)==0 else current_tag
)
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. This code however search through the entire sentence. I am just looking for the beginning of the sentence. I am using 'startswith' not contain for this reason. the id 3 and 5 should be `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version

```
df["tags"] = df["text"].str.split(" ").apply(lambda x: list(set(x) & set(
        searchwords)))
```

If you want `Nan` instead empty list, add following

```
import numpy as np 

df['tags'] = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(x)==0 else x)
```